# google spreadsheet script trigger stopped working 4 days ago

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet script using google spreadsheets that was firing on a daily trigger.  Everything was running fine until a few days ago and suddenly it stopped working.  The script sends me an email every day, around midnight. I was able to send a test email today but the operation that pulls data from my spreadsheet doesnt seem to be able to send the email.  Ran it through the debugger and everything appears to be working fine.  Does anyone know why something like this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out whether or not your trigger is being invoked. If yes, click on notifications in the triggers window to set it up so that you receive an error email immediately. This way you'll see if your script gets any errors which might be useful in determining the next step.